# ObjectMapper conditional mapping whole element

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, objectmapper

I have a custom ObjectMapper class.
I want to map the element to different object types based on the data.
I have implemented the logic like below. But it's not giving me the values, only null.

```
class FeedObject : Object, Mappable {

    dynamic var post : HomeDataModel?
    dynamic var friends : Friends?

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        var Mtype = ""
        Mtype <- map["type"]
        print("TYPEEEEEE", Mtype)

        if Mtype == "FRIENDS" {
            friends <- map
        }
        else {
            post <- map
        }
    }
}
```

How can I implement this kind of mapping?

Sample Json -

`{
  "feed_objects": [
    {
      "type": "NORMAL",
      "status": "none",
      "invited": false,
      "comment": "hello",
      "time": "00:12"
    },
    {
      "type": "NORMAL",
      "status": "none",
      "invited": true,
      "comment": "How are you?",
      "time": "04:15"
    },
    {
      "type": "FRIENDS",
      "display_text": "Your friends are here.",
      "count": 23
    },
    {
      "type": "NORMAL",
      "status": "verified",
      "invited": true,
      "comment": "great",
      "time": "09:32"
    }]
}`

Comment: Can you share a JSON response?

Comment: @anilkukdeja added sample json

Comment: Please check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I think you should store entire array object.

Here let's go to your web service parsing method where you are getting response.

```
if let responseValue = response.result.value as? [String:AnyObject]{ 
    if let feedObject = Mapper<Feed>().mapArray(JSONArray:data){
             print(feedObject)
    }
}
```

Define your Feed class is something like this.

```
import ObjectMapper

class Feed: Mappable, CustomStringConvertible {

    required init?(map: Map) {}

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        type <- map["type"]
        status <- map["status"]
        comment <- map["comment"]
        time <- map["time"]
        invited <- map["invited"]
    }

    var description: String {
        get {
            return Mapper().toJSONString(self, prettyPrint: false)!
        }
    }

     var type:String = String()
     var status:String = String()
     var comment:String = String()
     var time:String = String()
     var invited : Bool = Bool()

}
```

After that you can iterate through your array object and compare the types. Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: I have also prepared seprate demo for this. Let me know if you require a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Anil's answer is not the right/efficient way, where you will re-process the data set after one mapping iteration. 
You need to define your own Transform for the mapping. Check this out : [How to map different type using ObjectMapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330913/how-to-map-different-type-using-objectmapper)